# Vue JS nested loop search not returning results

Tags: javascript, search, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a key-command resource and giving VueJS a whirl while doing so. I'm a newbie but am gaining the grasp of things (slowly...).

I want to be able to search in a global search form for key commands I'm defining as **actions** within sections of commands (see data example below). I would like to search through all the actions to show only those that match the search criteria.

My HTML is below:

```
<div id="commands">

  <input v-model="searchQuery" />

  <div class="commands-section" v-for="item in sectionsSearched" 
:key="item.id">

    <h3>{{ item.section }}</h3>

    <div class="commands-row" v-for="command in item.command" :key="command.action"> 
          {{ command.action }}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My main Vue instance looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import { commands } from  './data.js'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const element = document.getElementById("commands")

  if (element != null) {

  const app = new Vue({
    el: element,
    data: {
      searchQuery: '',
      commands: commands
    },
    computed: {
      sectionsSearched() {
        var self = this;
        return this.commands.filter((c) => {
          return c.command.filter((item) => {
            console.log(item.action)
            return item.action.indexOf(self.searchQuery) > -1;
           });
          });
        },
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And finally the data structure in `data.js`

```
const commands = [
  {
     section: "first section",
     command: [
       { action: '1' },
       { action: '2' },
       { action: '3' },
     ],
  },
  {
     section: "second section",
     command: [
       { action: 'A' },
       { action: 'B' },
       { action: 'C' },
     ]
  },  
]

export { commands };
```

I'm able to output the commands using the `console.log(item.action)` snippet you see in the computed method called `sectionsSearched`.

I see no errors in the browser and the data renders correctly.

I **cannot** however filter by searching in real-time. I'm nearly positive it's a combination of my data structure + the computed method. Can anyone shed some insight as to what I'm doing wrong here?

I'd ideally like to keep the data as is because it's important to be sectioned off.

I'm a Rails guy who is new to this stuff so any and all feedback is welcome.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've tried the proposed solutions below but keep getting `undefined` in any query I pass. The functionality seems to work in most cases for something like this:

```
 sectionsSearched() {
      return this.commands.filter((c) => {
        return c.command.filter((item) => {
          return item.action.indexOf(this.searchQuery) > -1;
         }).length > 0;
      });
    },
```

But alas nothing actually comes back. I'm scratching my head hard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue in your `sectionsSearched` as it is returning the array of just commands.

See this one

```
sectionsSearched() {
  return this.commands.reduce((r, e) => {
    const command = e.command.filter(item => item.action.indexOf(this.searchQuery) > -1);
    const section = e.section;
    r.push({
      section,
      command
    });
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Unfortunately, it gives me an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle if it helps troubleshoot. [https://jsfiddle.net/justalever/kuqnfsr3/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/justalever/kuqnfsr3/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const commands = [
  {
     section: "first section",
     command: [
       { action: '1' },
       { action: '2' },
       { action: '3' },
     ],
  },
  {
     section: "second section",
     command: [
       { action: 'A' },
       { action: 'B' },
       { action: 'C' },
     ]
  },  
]

const element = document.getElementById("commands")

  if (element != null) {

  const app = new Vue({
    el: element,
    data: {
      searchQuery: '',
      commands: commands
    },
    computed: {
      sectionsSearched() {
        var self = this;
        return this.commands.filter((c) => {
        
         // the code below return an array, not a boolean
         // make this.commands.filter() not work
         
         // return c.command.filter((item) => {
         //   return item.action.indexOf(self.searchQuery) > -1;
         //  });
         
         // to find whether there has command action equal to searchQuery
          return c.command.find(item => item.action === self.searchQuery);
         });
        },
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="commands">

  <input v-model="searchQuery" />

  <div class="commands-section" v-for="item in sectionsSearched" 
:key="item.id">

    <h3>{{ item.section }}</h3>

    <div class="commands-row" v-for="command in item.command" :key="command.action"> 
          {{ command.action }}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Is that work as you wish ?

Comment: It seems like this should work but when I do a console.log of  
`console.log(c.command.find(item => item.action === self.searchQuery))` 
and try a search everything I enter comes back as `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: This also only returns output of the first section. I need it for all sections and commands

Comment: When input A, the `console.log(c.command.find(item => item.action === self.searchQuery))` will output `{action:"A"}`.And input 2 will out put `{action: "2"}`It only output undefined when your input doesn't match any actions.

Comment: And the code works fine.If your purpose is when input exactly equal to'A' or 'B' or 'C', the whole Section B will show.And  when input exactly equal to 1 or 2 or 3 the whole Section A will show. Or if you want to do  fuzzy search, this code will not work.And maybe you should change the compare logic to `c.command.find(item => self.searchQuery.includes(item.action))`

Answer (score 0):

```
sectionsSearched() {
    return this.commands.filter((c) => {
      return c.command.filter((item) => {
        return item.action.indexOf(this.searchQuery) > -1;
       }).length > 0;
    });
    },
  }
```

since filter will always return an array(empty or not) which value always is true.

Comment: Thanks for this. This has gotten me the farthest. Currently I'm getting no results when I perform a search and the query matches the command. Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: In which case can you get a undefined?